# Find the view located in the end of RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android

The below code is to locate the view on the first position. How do I locate the view on the last position ***simply & efficiently***?

```
TextView textView = 
  (TextView)myRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(0).itemView.findViewById(R.id.myTV); //this is first position
```

Comment: You can pass the size of the list -1 in `position` `findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position)`.

Comment: How are you populating your recyclerView? What array do you pass there?

Comment: @JohnC With `-1` I get error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.view.View android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.itemView' on a null object reference`

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
TextView textView =(TextView)myRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(mAppsListAdapter.getItemCount()-1).itemView.findViewById(R.id.myTV);
```

Comment: mAppsListAdapter is red in my project...

Comment: I just mentioned my dummy adapter name here you will have to give your adapter name that you have bind with your recycler view.

Comment: How do I find the name?

Comment: have you set bind adapter with your recycler view? then just use object of that adapter.

Comment: have you set bind adapter with your recycler view? no I did not. what should I do? and is this necessary?